# How to store fragment data when switching from one fragment to another in android?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-studio

I have 2 fragments.in one fragment i am accessing server JSON data.
On switching the fragment the data is accessed again and again.
How do i temporarily store this data till the app is open so that the data is not again and again accessed from the server.

Comment: Create a static class. Class should contain all member variables that are being received from server in JSON. Store all values in those static member variables.

Comment: How are you switching fragments? ViewPager or what?

Comment: You can pass a bundle between them.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of options that trade-off **efficiency** (how fast is  saving/loading of data) with **persistence** (how long data will remain in memory).

All of the following solutions persist configuration changes (e.g. orientation change), which is typically the minimum level of persistence needed for a good user experience.

```
|      Method        |  Efficiency  |            Persistence                 |
+--------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------+
| SharedPreferences  |     Bad      | until app uninstall                    |
| SavedInstanceState |     Bad      | until app finished                     |
| Bundle/Extra       |     Bad      | until app finished                     |
| Database           |     Ok       | until app uninstall                    |
| Application        |     Good     | until app restart                      |
| Singleton          |     Good     | until app restart                      |
| EventBus (Sticky)  |     Good     | until app restart                      |
| Retain Fragment    |     Good     | until Activity finished or app restart |
```

**DETAILS:**

- **app finished** = user closed app
- **app restart**  = system closed app (low memory)
- **Bad** efficiency = need to do a lot of work:

  - **save:** json => str => disk
  - **load:** disk => str => json
- **Ok** efficiency = less work (no string parsing):

  - **save:** json => database
  - **load:** database => json
- **Good** efficiency = object reference is retained in memory, so no work needed.

Notice however, that all of the "Good" efficiency methods have short persistence because they are all limited by an app restart, which happens in low memory situations. Because low memory situations can happen at any time, I usually combine these methods with **savedInstanceState**, which can save the data right before exiting due to low memory.

Also note that storing data for longer than you need is also not good, so choose a persistence that matches your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can store json string in shared prefernces for temporary purpose, so that you will not have to access data from server again and again.

```
 SharedPreferences shared;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            shared = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            shared.edit().putString("JSON",jsonString).commit();
}
```